# Designing APIs with many parameters

Tags: objective-c, api

I'm designing an API for the iPhone. What is the best way to design API functions that take many arguments (maybe up to 20 variables). Is it better to pass in a custom object with the necessary fields defined, a generic key-value dictionary (NSDictionary in Obj-C), or just list them all out? What other suggestions are available?

I'm tending towards declaring an object for each API, but since there are many APIs I need to define, I am leery of using this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Most API designers agree that you should avoid long argument lists if possible, e.g., Joshua Bloch (Effective Java) suggests that 5 or more is too many. Some ways to avoid this include:

1. Create a struct to hold the arguments and pass that single struct to the function. This is often called a Plain Old Data (POD) type. You may want to add a helper function to create the structure that sets the default values (or if you're using Objective-C++ you could define a constructor for the struct to do the same). If you think the list of arguments may change over time and binary compatibility is important to you, you could add a version field and have the constructor set it appropriately. That way, your code can check the version number to know what fields are available.
2. Pass a dictionary of values. This is effectively a data-driven API, where arguments and their values are passed in a structure that supports keys with arbitrarily-typed values. In C/C++ you'd have to create this structure yourself or use something like boost::any or Qt's QVariant. But, as you note, NSDictionary lets you hold objects of type id so you could use that. The nice thing about this is that changing the list of arguments doesn't break your interface - it's just up to the implementation to detect the new keys and support older keys. Though an implication of this is that your compiler won't catch incorrect keys for you - it's up to your code. The main downside is that just looking at your API doesn't tell a user what keys are supported so this approach must be supported by good documentation.
3. Create an object and turn arguments into method calls. This has the benefit of being able to specify arguments in any order, to essentially name arguments, and to still handle optional arguments (by simply not calling a given method). Adding new parameters is also backward compatible as it resolves to adding a new function to the object.
4. Building on 3., you could use the Named Parameter Idiom (NPI), where each function returns a pointer or reference to the object, thus allowing you to chain calls together. This option has all the benefits of 3. but also allows for more terse syntax, e.g., MyObject().setValue(100).setName("Hello").setEnabled(true);

It sounds like you've considered most of these options already, so I'm probably not telling you anything new. For my own preference, I would tend more toward the NPI style as it avoids long parameter lists, is strongly-typed, names each argument, is backward compatible, and still offers a relatively compact syntax. It's more typing (for you) than the NSDictionary approach, but importantly it's easy for your users to use and it makes the set of supported 'arguments' obvious (and always correct) via your header files even without any documentation, unlike an NSDictionary solution.

Answer (score 2):

If your API really really needs 20 parameters, use 20 parameters.  If it makes sense to aggregate some or all of those parameters into a custom object, by all means, do that but do not create a custom object just for the sake of making your parameter list smaller.  As a simple example, if a method takes the coordinates of a point (x, y, z) it is legitimate to create an object to model a point and pass that as a single parameter.  You should not be creating objects whose sole purpose is to model an API parameter list.

I would only use the NSDictionary approach in the case where I really do have an extensible set of key value pairs all of which really are optional.  The reason for not using it in other situations is that if the programmer using the API omits a mandatory parameter, the error cannot be detected until run time.  A parameter list explicitly naming each parameter allows the compiler to detect omissions.

The idea that the number of parameters of an API must be limited to an arbitrary small value is completely bogus.  The API should take exactly as many parameters as it needs.

Answer (score 1):

You need 20 arguments to just init the object?  You want a few arguments to init the object to a default state.  Then use properties to change it states.

Internally, you can store the 20 arguments/states in NSDictionary for easy maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the type of API you are creating.

If it is for a service with a commonly understood information model, having custom model objects is probably a good idea since they tend to ease understanding of the API as a whole.

OTOH, if it is more of a generic API, quite a few of the arguments are optional or the model objects would be unique for each method, you are probably better of using a NSDictionary, with clear documentation of the keys you are expecting (as well as proper checking at the start of the function).

There is also a breadth of information on the topic on the interwebs, see ["How to Design a Good API and Why it Matters"](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf) for good ideas, [ProgrammableWeb](http://www.programmableweb.com/) for good examples and  ["Top Ten ways to create a great API"](http://thesocialbazaar.com/2007/11/26/top-ten-ways-to-create-a-great-api/) for a top-ten list-style of advice.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The most complex methods I can think of right now take an NSDictionary as argument. I would do it like that.